# No hint path define for [erros] laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

While creating error exceptions in `laravel 5.7`, I have got Exception called `"No hint path define for [errors]"`. Kindly provide the solution.

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) No hint path defined for [errors]. (View:
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\putinbasket\resources\views\errors\404.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions No hint path defined for [errors]. (0)

Comment: Attach the code of the exception handler, please.

Comment: And are you making a custom 404 page?

Comment: No. I am using laravel's 404 page

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if you use bellow command for create error pages:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

then you should edit all pages (eg `404.blade.php`) and change

`errors::minimal`  code to `errors.minimal`

note that minimal or layout or illustrated-layout is like that and must exists
in resources/view/errors folder

Comment: Is it a bug or..? I have to fix this even in Laravel 6.5, no one recognized it yet?

Comment: I came all the ways here from past 3hours just to change this "@extends('errors.minimal')"....God knows why :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish Laravel’s default error layout by running this command:

```sh
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

Then you can extend the error layout and create own error pages.
Also, I would recommend you to read the documentation about [custom HTTP error pages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#custom-http-error-pages).

Comment: Then attach the handler and the error page you have.